# Rails console output to recreate objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I accidentally deleted 1000 objects from a database and now trying to recreate these objects.  Thankfully I was able to scroll through my console output and find the records. I copy and pasted the console output which is in this (greatly shortened) format:

```
[#<Assignment id: 276503, school_id: 2091, listing_id: 251572, created_at: "2018-08-30 05:02:36", updated_at: "2018-08-30 05:02:36">, #<Assignment id: 279532, school_id: 1233, listing_id: 252702, created_at: "2018-08-30 06:19:12", updated_at: "2018-08-30 06:19:12">]
#...
```

I can't get the console to assign this output to a variable so I can figure out how to use this data to recreate the objects in the db:

```
irb(main):040:0> a = [#<Assignment id: 276503, school_id: 2091, listing_id: 251572, created_at: "2018-08-30 05:02:36", updated_at: "2018-08-30 05:02:36">, #<Assignment id: 279532, school_id: 1233, listing_id: 252702, created_at: "2018-08-30 06:19:12", updated_at: "2018-08-30 06:19:12">]
irb(main):041:1*
```

Does anyone have ideas how to turn this console output back into objects in my db?

Comment: Just do `Assignment.create(id: 276503, school_id: 2091, created_at: Time.parse("2018-08-30 05:02:36", ...)`. You can generate these lines by processing the content you have with regular expressions, for example. But if you don't know regexes and nobody posts a solution, then a few hours of furiously copy-pasting info should do the job.

Comment: Sergio, thanks for the comment. I definitely could do that but hoping for a solution that doesn't take a few hours!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the problems with assigning a huge array to a variable in the console, you can try to use rake task.

```
    array.each do |e|
      options = e.split(',')
      school_id = options.detect{|i| i.match?(/school_id/)}.split(':').last
      listing_id = options.detect{|i| i.match?(/listing_id/)}.split(':').last
      Assignment.create(school_id: school_id, listing_id: listing.id)
    end
```

This should work. It is quite consuming, but from another perspective easy and fast.

Answer (score 0):

I would paste that output on sublime or any other text editor and then format 
 to become something useful... 
A bunch of `inserts` using SQL or just `.create()` that i would then paste it on the console

Comment: Thanks Vipkry, I will end up doing this tomorrow if a less time consuming options doesn't materialize.

Comment: Sure, no problem. It's worth noting that you can use multiple line selection to speed up the formatting though